# Cannot access Contract from Opportunity in Visualforce

Tags: visualforce, opportunity

In a VF page I'm writing, working with the Opportunity standard controller, I'm trying to reference the Contract, like this:

```
<apex:inputField value="{!Opportunity.Contract.Name}"/>
```

I'm getting this error:

> Invalid field Contract for SObject Opportunity

How can I access the Contract from Opportunity?

Answer (score 1):

I think you cannot directly set values to relationship fields using input field. For example,

```
<apex:inputField value="{!Opportunity.Contract.Name}"/>
```

will not work. Even if you get it to show the input field in page, it will not set value to the Name field in contract. You can only set fields in opportunity through . If you are trying to update related contract, you need to initialize a contract variable in controller and use like below,

```
<apex:inputField value="{!contractInstance.Name}"/>
```

Then finally in the controller set `opportunity.Contract = contractInstance.Id;`

Comment: and if I use outputfield?

Comment: Outputfield will be fine.